# Undefined is not a function when using array.splice

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to remove some elements from an array, and use the `splice` functionality where it also returns those values. See the javascript below:

```
var blocksUsed = allNumbers.splice(0,3);
```

When trying to run this line (in conjunction with the entire function), I get an error saying the following:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

I have spent quite some time looking for typographical errors in the function, but there don't seem to be any. I also ready that JQuery is the common troublemaker here, but I am not using JQuery.

The array is created by shuffling another array (the shuffle function isn't mine):

```
function shuffle(o){
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};
```

Which I then use in the following manner:

```
var allNumbers = shuffle(blocks);
```

I tried logging the allNumbers, which works correctly. The array gets shuffled correctly. Trying to do a splice on this however gives a same error.

Also note that I am doing the splicing inside a for-loop. Code below.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){

    // Get a block of 3 blocks.
    var blocksUsed = allNumbers.splice(0,3); // This line gives the error.

    // Determine the color used for these blocks and remove it so that it doesn't get drawn again.
    var colorIndex = randomIntFromInterval(0,i);
    var colorUsed = otherColors[colorIndex];
    if(otherColors.indexOf(colorUsed) > -1){
        otherColors.splice(colorIndex, 1);
    }

    // For each block, set the color.
    for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        blocksUsed[j].className = "block " + colorUsed;
    }
}
```

Why can I not use `splice` on this array? Note that I can provide the entire function, if desired. I have the entire function at this [codepen](http://codepen.io/mlangendijk92/pen/qEbQqg) for reference straight away.

Because of the comment:

`allNumbers` is a shuffled version of an array containing elements received in the following manner:

```
var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName('block');
```

Comment: It is an array of div-elements.

Comment: `blocks` isn't an array, it's a `NodeList`. So is `allNumbers`.

Comment: `for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);` is the nastiest line of code I've seen in a while.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName('block');
```

That is not an array. It is array like. You need to make it into an array.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('block');
var blocks = Array.prototype.slice.call( elems, 0 );
```

Answer (score 5):

`blocks` is not an `Array`. It's a `NodeList` So you need to use `[].slice.call` which will take blocks, which is an array-like structure and return expected results.

```
var blocksArr = [].slice.call(blocks, 0); 
var blocksUSed = blocksArr.splice(0, 3);
```

Comment: Don't use `splice`! The nodelist will throw an error upon attempts to modify it!

Comment: @Bergi never heard of this. Any links? Any way I changed it

Comment: I just tried it out and got an Exception `Failed to update length`. Which makes only sense as [`length` is specced to be readonly](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177).

Comment: @Matthijs: Yes, now it does. [This revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27383728/1) didn't.

Comment: @Matthijs I'm happy with +15 but perhaps it is epascarello who answered it correctly from the first and deserves it more. Bergi, thanks for that. Didn't knew it.

Comment: @AmitJoki: fair enough ;)